# downloaded content using NSURLConnection does not display on my iPhone?

Tags: ios, path, download, nsurlconnection

i am using NSURLConnection to download mp3 files from server, my code is

```
- (IBAction)download:(id)sender 
 {
NSURL *url = [NSURL      URLWithString:@"http://viadj.viastreaming.net/start/psalmsmedia/ondemand/Nin%20snehamethrayo.mp3"];    
   NSLog(@"%@", url);
   NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url   cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60];
   receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:0];
   NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self startImmediately:YES];


 }

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
  [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
  [receivedData setLength:0];
 }

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
[receivedData appendData:data];

 }

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error 
  {

  [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
  [connection release];

  }

- (NSCachedURLResponse *) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponse 
  {

  return nil;

  }

 - (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
 {

  [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

  NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myFile.mp3"];

  [receivedData writeToFile:documentsDirectoryPath atomically:YES];

  [connection release];

  }
```

when i click download button, the activity indicator start animating and stops after some time (i think it is downloading). but after that i can't find the downloaded file on my iPhone disk. actually where those files stored after downloading.
i have edited my info.plist to support iTunes file sharing.

is their any mistake with this code? or why can't i see the downloaded files?

Answer (score 0):

My Created one class for downloading ringtones, See first RingtoneDwonloader.h file

## import

@protocol RingtoneDownloaderDelegate 
-(void)downloadingCompleted;

@end

@interface RingtoneDownloader : NSObject
{
    NSMutableData *receivedData;
    NSDate *connectionTime;
    NSMutableString *diskPath;

```
id<RingtoneDownloaderDelegate>delegate;
```

}
@property(nonatomic, retain) iddelegate;

-(void)createUrlRequestForDownloadRingtone:(NSString *)urlString;
-(void)cancelDownloading;

@end

Now my RingtoneDownloader.m file,

## import "RingtoneDownloader.h"

## import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface RingtoneDownloader(){
    AppDelegate *_appDelegate;
    NSURLConnection *theConnection;
}
@end

```
  @implementation RingtoneDownloader
  @synthesize delegate;
  -(void)createUrlRequestForDownloadRingtone:(NSString *)urlString{

_appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]  cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];

// create the connection with the request
// and start loading the data

theConnection =[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

if (theConnection) {
    // Create the NSMutableData to hold the received data.
    receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
} else {
    // Inform the user that the connection failed.
}
```

}

```
       - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
```

{
    // This method is called when the server has determined that it
    [receivedData setLength:0];
//    long responseLength = [response expectedContentLength];
//    NSLog(@"%ld", responseLength);
}

```
      - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
```

{
    // Append the new data to receivedData.
    [receivedData appendData:data];
}

```
      - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
```

{
    // release the connection, and the data object
    [theConnection release];
    // receivedData is declared as a method instance elsewhere
    [receivedData release];

```
UIAlertView *alt = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [error localizedDescription]] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[alt show];
[alt release];
// inform the user         
NSLog(@"Connection failed! Error - %@ %@", [error localizedDescription], [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);
```

}

```
       - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

{
    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[receivedData length]);
    // release the connection, and the data object

```
 _appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSString *soundFileName = _appDelegate.ringtoneURL;
NSString *soundFileextension =  [soundFileName substringFromIndex:([soundFileName length]-3)];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", _appDelegate.ringtoneText, soundFileextension]];
NSData *imageData = (NSData *)receivedData;
NSError *err = nil;
BOOL isWriten = [imageData writeToFile:filePath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&err];    

if(!isWriten){
    NSLog(@"Ringtone not saved   %@", [err localizedDescription]);
}

[theConnection release];
[receivedData release];    
[delegate downloadingCompleted];
```

}

```
   -(void)cancelDownloading{
[theConnection cancel];
[theConnection release];
[delegate downloadingCompleted];
```

}

Now u have to just created and instance of this class and set the delegate that i m  create. That delegate give u information regarding your ringtone file is successfully downloaded or not.

Use iTunes file sharing in your app and copy the ringtone file to the app's documents directory.

```
Set "Application supports iTunes file sharing" to YES in your info.plist
```

The user can now access the ringtone via itunes and add it to their devices ringtones.

Comment: where is this file actually downloaded to? document directory? sorry am just a beginner ,let me ask how will i retrieve files from document directory? or can i download the files to my local iPhone drive so that i can play after downloading it!

Comment: @NeerajNeeru, see ur file in mac or even u connected iphone with mac... the file location on the path /Users/macUserName/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/urAppBundleID/Documents

Comment: @NeerajNeeru, yes u can also play that file using document directory path give to Audioplayer

Comment: i have connected my iPhone and tested the app  and downloaded the file to /var/mobile/Applications/6707BA92-BC73-428F-80F5-184DE872BA3F/Documents/myFile.jpg   (for testing only i used jpg file). actually where can i possible to see this file on my iPhone?

Comment: i mean after downloading  i am closing my application and want to play that song from local disk

Comment: @NeerajNeeru, you can play directly from local disk... otherwise take in u have to copy directory path where u saved or located your sound file and give it to MediaPlayer. Using MediaPlayer u can play also that sound file inside the application.

Comment: @NeerajNeeru,  NSURL *ringtoneUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:soundFilePath];
        _mediaPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:ringtoneUrl];
        [_mediaPlayer prepareToPlay];
        [_mediaPlayer play];